# Adding JPanel on another JPanel on button press

Tags: java, swing, menu, jpanel, visibility

I have created a `MainPanel` in which I make a bird fly. To this panel, I have to add a `PausePanel` panel at the press of a button. If I only use `pausePanel.setVisible (true / false)` when pressing the key, this works. But, if the bird starts before the first keypress, the panel will never be displayed.

I, therefore, thought of adding and removing the `PausePanel` every time I press the key. Unfortunately, the game pauses but the `PausePanel` does not appear.

Here's the code:

**PausePanel:**

```java
public class PausePanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3943280654281528696L;
    private final JLabel resumeLabel = new JLabel("ESC: RESUME", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private final JLabel exitLabel = new JLabel("ENTER: EXIT THE GAME", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private final MainFontLoader fontLoader = new MainFontLoader();
    private final Font gameFont = fontLoader.load();

    public PausePanel() {
        exitLabel.setFont(gameFont);
        resumeLabel.setFont(gameFont);
        resumeLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        exitLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.NORTH);
        resumeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        exitLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.add(resumeLabel);
        this.add(exitLabel);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
    
    public boolean getVisibility() {
        return this.isVisible();
    }
}
```

Here I need the `getVisibility` method for another `ExitButton` that should only work when this panel is visible.

**PauseButton:**

```java
public class PauseButton {

    private boolean pause = false;
    
    public PauseButton(JPanel mainPanel, JPanel pausePanel, BirdVisual visual) {

        final KeyStroke escKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
        mainPanel.getInputMap().put(escKey, "Esc");
        mainPanel.getActionMap().put("Esc", new AbstractAction(){
            
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -534997922777581539L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisibility(mainPanel, pausePanel, visual);
        }
    });
}

    public void setVisibility(JPanel mainPanel, JPanel pausePanel, BirdVisual visual) {
        if(!pause){
            mainPanel.add(pausePanel);
            pausePanel.setVisible(true);
            pausePanel.revalidate();
            pausePanel.repaint();
            visual.setPause();
            pause = true;
        } else {
            mainPanel.remove(pausePanel);
            pausePanel.setVisible(false);
            visual.setPause();
            pause = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPanel:**

```java
public class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5567586066880648121L;
    private PausePanel pausePanel = new PausePanel();
    private final BirdVisual visual = new BirdVisual(this);

    
    public MainPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        new PauseButton(this, pausePanel, visual);
        new ExitButton(this, pausePanel);
    }

    public BirdVisual getVisual() {
        return this.visual;
    }

}
```

Comment: So is this new panel supposed to appear in a space in the GUI that is already defined? [If so, use a `CardLayout`.] **BTW:** `this.setLayout(null);` Don't do that.

Comment: This new panel should cover all the space of the mainPanel. I tried using this.setLayout(new BorderLayout); and than mainPanel.add(pausePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); but it doesn't work

Comment: *"This new panel should cover all the space of the mainPanel."* It seems then like a `CardLayout` is the way to go. It is designed to flip between panels (or components).